# Apache2 vhost config error

Tags: apache-2.2

When I access one of my domains which are configured in the vhosts file, I see a listed directory (Index Of).

This is how every domain is configured currently:

```
<VirtualHost ip:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/home
</VirtualHost>
```

Although I have no *.htaccess* and the domain directory is completely empty.
So why don't I see the default msg "You dont have permission to view this..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the Indexes property you can see directory indexes. Add the following to your vhost configuration file to turn that feature on:

```
Options +Indexes
```

To turn this feature off use:

```
Options -Indexes
```

When indexing is off or the directory is empty you'll see a 403 forbidden error page instead.

Comment: I know but I have NOWHERE such setting ... that is my actual problem.

Comment: @Mellnik Prior to 2.3.11 it's the default. So if you don't specify it, then you get indexes.

Comment: Where you add that ? on .htaccess or directly on vhost ? in vhost you need ad a direcotry directive: <Directory /var/www/domain.com/home> then add there your options -indexes followsymlinks etc etc